# If $G, H$ are relations in a set $A$ and $G \circ H = H \circ G$, how to prove that $G \circ H$ is transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The full theorem say that G∘H is a equivalence relation, but i couldn't prove that G∘H is transitive. I have:

Let $(x,y)\in G\circ H \land (y,z)\in G\circ H$

$\implies (\exists v\in A)((x,v)\in H \land(v,y)\in G) \land
(\exists u\in A)((y,u)\in H \land(u,z)\in G)$

$\implies (\exists v\in A \land u\in A)((x,v)\in H \land(v,y)\in G \land 
(y,u)\in H \land(u,z)\in G)$

But, i can't see how to get $(x,z)\in G \circ H$. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

$I_A$ commutes with any binary relation in $A$ in a relative product, so (assuming $\circ$ is meant to represent relative product) what you state would imply that all relations in $A$ are transitive, which is patently false.

Try $G=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$, $H=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$.

It probably should have said that $G$ and $H$ are transitive.

In this case $(G\circ H)^2=G^2\circ H^2\subset G\circ H$ hence $G\circ H$ is transitive.

In fact for what you state as the full theorem you probably should have said $G$ and $H$ are equivalence relations (otherwise the other requirements for $G\circ H$ to be an equivalence relation would also fail in general).